# Is $\lVert u \rVert_{L^2(M)} + \lVert \Delta u \rVert_{L^2(M)}$ equivalent to $\lVert u \rVert_{H^2(M)}$?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, manifolds, sobolev-spaces

On a bounded Riemannian manifold without boundary, is it true that the norms
$$\lVert u \rVert_{L^2(M)} + \lVert \Delta u \rVert_{L^2(M)}$$ is equivalent to the full $H^2$ norm $\lVert u \rVert_{H^2(M)}$?

Can i have a reference to this please?

Thanks

Comment: I think that is true if $u\in H^2_0(M)$ from Sobolev inequality

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that's actually true. First, note that the inequality
$$
||u||_{L^2} + ||\Delta u ||_{L^2} \leq c ||u||_{H^2}
$$
is always true (the constant may vary due to your definition though). Hence it remains to show that
$$
||u||_{H^2} \leq C \left(  ||u||_{L^2} + ||\Delta u ||_{L^2} \right).
$$
This follows from the fact that the Laplacian is elliptic and can e.g. be found in the book "Spin Geometry" by H. Blaine Lawson and Marie-Louise Michelsohn, see Theorem 5.2 (iii) in Chapter III, page 193.